# simple hierarchical select widget type name

Tags: 7

I'm programming a custom content type. I need to select some childs inside a parent taxonomy. I want to use [simple hierarchical select](https://drupal.org/project/shs)

I can't seem to find the

```
widget => 'widget name'
```

for it.

I tried

```
shs_taxonomy
taxonomy_shs
select_shs
shs_select
```

none seem to work.

Has anyone got some experience on this?

greetings
Thomas

Comment: you mentioned simple hierarchical select, but you linked to hierarchical select module.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Indeed it has to be https://drupal.org/project/shs